# How do I access my private variables from my static method

Tags: java, methods, instance

I have two private instance variables xCord and yCord. I have a public static method called getSlope that takes in two arguments of class Point. When I try to use .yCord or .xCord on them it says non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context.

I tried to use a public accessor method to get the x and y coordinates, however I got the same error message when I tried that. In the code snippets below my goal was to calculate the slope then print it out with a sentence format that included the individual coordinates that were involved in the calculation. I am new to coding so my ability to test is limited by what I know. The accessor methods are at the bottom. I also looked at the suggested questions that were answered already but none of it helped.

```
private double xCord;
private  double yCord;

public static String getSlope(Point other) {
        double slope = ((Point.yCord - other.yCord) / (Point.xCord - other.xCord));
        return "The slope of the line from " + "(" + Point.xCord + ", " + Point.yCord + ")" + " to " + "(" + other.xCord + ", " + "(" + other.xCord + ", " + other.yCord + ")" +  "is " + slope;
}

public double getXCord() {return this.xCord;}
public double getYCord() {return this.yCord;}
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to access per-instance private variables from any static method. If your method needs access to per-instance data then it shouldn't be static.

Comment: it cannot be a static method. Think about it. the slope you want to get is between one point and another, but static method means the method of getSlope belongs to the class of Point, and the calculation is done by deducting other.yCord by the ability of the Point class to have a yCord. doesnt make much sense if you think about it logically. So the method must belong to the instance itself, comparing "this" to the other point, or if static, takes two points for comparison. sorry if the analogy isnt quite right, not too sure how to word it

Comment: I just tried removing static from getSlope it put the whole method in red.

Comment: just change `Point.yCord` to `this.yCord`, and remove `static` in `getSlope`. Point is a class, I think what you want to do is using instance's `yCord`.

Comment: Your problem likely stems from a misunderstanding what static means, the details. You would probably benefit by reviewing a tutorial or two on this.

Comment: How do I know the location of an object that does not exist?

Answer (score 3):

1. Change `Point.yCord` to `this.yCord`. Point is a class, I think what you actually want to do is using instance of Point `yCord` to calculate with a new point `yCord`.
2. You need add `setter` method to set point member value, not just `getter`.
3. You need remove `static` in `getSlope`, Static methods are the methods that can be called without creating an object of class.  Apparently you are creating an object of Point.
4. A little fix to `getSlope` output format.

#### example code

- Point

```
public class Point {
    private double xCord;
    private double yCord;
    public String getSlope(Point other) {
        double slope = ((this.yCord - other.yCord) / (this.xCord - other.xCord));
        return "The slope of the line from " + "(" + this.xCord + ", " + this.yCord + ")" + " to "  + "(" + other.xCord + ", " + other.yCord + ")" +  " is " + slope;
    }
    public double getXCord() {return this.xCord;}
    public void setXCord(double cord) {this.xCord=cord;}
    public double getYCord() {return this.yCord;}
    public void setYCord(double cord) {this.yCord=cord;}
}
```

- main

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Point point = new Point();
        point.setXCord(0);
        point.setXCord(0);
        Point newPoint = new Point();
        newPoint.setXCord(1.00);
        newPoint.setYCord(1.00);
        System.out.println(point.getSlope(newPoint));
    }
```

- result:

```
The slope of the line from (0.0, 0.0) to (1.0, 1.0) is 1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

A static method cannot access non-static members/fields. Instead, write your function with a parameter for both `Point`s:

```
public static String getSlope1(Point a, Point b) {
    double slope = ((a.yCord - b.yCord) / (a.xCord - b.xCord));
    return "The slope of the line from " + "(" + a.xCord + ", " + a.yCord + ")" + " to " + "(" + b.xCord + ", " + b.yCord + ")" +  "is " + slope;
}
```

Alternatively, you could remove the `static` keyword and access members/fields with `this.xCord` or simply `xCord`:

```
public String getSlope2(Point other) {
    double slope = ((yCord - other.yCord) / (xCord - other.xCord));
    return "The slope of the line from " + "(" + xCord + ", " + yCord + ")" + " to " + "(" + other.xCord + ", " + other.yCord + ")" +  "is " + slope;
}
```

These must be called differently:

```
// #1
String x = getSlope1(p1, p2);
// #2
String y = p1.getSlope2(p2);
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I have two private instance variables xCord and yCord. I have a public static method called getSlope that takes in two arguments of class Point. When I try to use .yCord or .xCord on them it says non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context. ..."*

Here is the *Java* tutorial on the usage of the *static* keyword, within a *[class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html)*.
*[Understanding Class Members (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Classes and Objects)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)*.

Essentially, when a *[field](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html)*, or *[method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)*, is defined as *static*, you will not need an *[instance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)* to access them.
Similar to the *[Math](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html)* class, which is composed of all *static* *members*.

So, here is an example of an *instance* *field*, and an *instance* *method*.

```java
class ABC {
    String s;

    void f() {

    }
}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ABC abc = new ABC();
    String s = abc.s;
    abc.f();
}
```

And, here is an example of a *static* *field*, and a *static* *method*.

```java
class ABC {
    static String s;

    static void f() {

    }
}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = ABC.s;
    ABC.f();
}
```

> *"... I tried to use a public accessor method to get the x and y coordinates, however I got the same error message when I tried that. ..."*

The *[access modifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)* are used to define the access, when out-side of the class.

For example, if you declare the *f* *method* as *private*, you would not be able to access it, from the *main* *method*.

You would receive the following *compilation error*.

```
java: f() has private access in ABC
```

Although, the reason you're receiving the specific error you've mentioned, is because the *xCord* and *yCord* are *instance fields*, and not *static fields*.

> *"... my goal was to calculate the slope then print it out with a sentence format that included the individual coordinates that were involved in the calculation. ..."*

Since you're *method* is static, you'll need two parameters; one for each *Point*.

This is similar to the *[Integer#compare](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,int))* *method*, and not like the *[String#compareTo](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String))* *method*.

Here is an example of both.

```java
static String getSlope(Point a, Point b) {
    double slope = ((a.yCord - b.yCord) / (a.xCord - b.xCord));
    return "The slope of the line from " + "(" + a.xCord + ", " + a.yCord + ")" + " to " + "(" + b.xCord + ", " + "(" + b.xCord + ", " + b.yCord + ")" +  "is " + slope;
}
```

```java
String getSlope(Point p) {
    double slope = ((yCord - p.yCord) / (xCord - p.xCord));
    return "The slope of the line from " + "(" + xCord + ", " + yCord + ")" + " to " + "(" + p.xCord + ", " + "(" + p.xCord + ", " + p.yCord + ")" +  "is " + slope;
}
```

And, it's worth noting, I believe your arithmetic is backwards.
A slope is typically calculated as *m = (y<sub>2</sub> − y<sub>1</sub>) / (x<sub>2</sub> − x<sub>1</sub>)*.
*[Wikipedia – Slope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope)*.

Here is a re-factor.

```java
class Point {
    double x, y;

    Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    static String slope(Point a, Point b) {
        double m = (b.y - a.y) / (b.x - a.x);
        return "m = (%s - %s) / (%s - %s) = %s".formatted(b.y, a.y, b.x, a.x, m);
    }
}
```

Output

```
m = (8.0 - 2.0) / (13.0 - 1.0) = 0.5
```

Alternately, use a *[record class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/language/records.html)*.

```java
record Point(double x, double y) {
    static String slope(Point a, Point b) {
        double m = (b.y - a.y) / (b.x - a.x);
        return "m = (%s - %s) / (%s - %s) = %s".formatted(b.y, a.y, b.x, a.x, m);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The error you're encountering, "non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context," is because you are trying to access instance variables (xCord and yCord) directly within a static method (getSlope) without creating an instance of the Point class.

To fix this issue, you should create an instance of the Point class and then use the accessor methods to retrieve the coordinates.

```
public static String getSlope(Point point1, Point point2) {
    double x1 = point1.getXCord();
    double y1 = point1.getYCord();
    double x2 = point2.getXCord();
    double y2 = point2.getYCord();

    double slope = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);

    return "The slope of the line from (" + x1 + ", " + y1 + ") to (" + x2 + ", " + y2 + ") is " + slope;
}
```